# emacs lisp: how to set tab key to bind different function?

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to set the tab key to map a function.
In my application, with tab I have to select next window in screen.
I tried to define a simple function that displays a message; I used (global-set-key) to map this function on "M-h"
(global-set-key (kbd "M-h") 'hello)
It worked, message is displayed.
Now, I tried same thing with tab-key
(global-set-key "\t" 'hello)
Apparently I don't receive any error.
But, tab key doesn't display anything.
I'm using emacs on windows, but tab key works correctly in other situations.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure what's wrong, doing

```
(defun hello () (interactive) (message "hi!"))

(global-set-key "\t" 'hello)
```

seems to work fine for me. Does your `hello` function look similar? The only thing I can think to suggest is trying `(kbd "TAB")` rather than `"\t"` in the call to `global-set-key`. A lot of code I've seen in the wild and that I've written in my config does this. I'm not sure if there's any difference, but it's worth a shot!